# Send Username and Password to .net Web Service using Spring .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, authentication, spring.net

I am developing a .net application using Web Services, and the application is consuming them using Spring.Net WebServiceProxyFactory.

I need to send to the web service the username and password of the user that is logged in to the application, consuming the web service.

Reading some forum post (like this http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=4818) they seem to refer to an example that used to be in the spring documentation ( http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/webservices.html ), an example of how using SOAP headers for authentication using the WebServiceExporter and WebServiceProxyFactory, but the link to the file is broken.

Do you know a way that I can send the user credentials as a soap header using spring.net? Or any data (for example, a token ID that the web service will use later to get the user credentials).

Thanks.

Comment: I've been reading several forum post about using an AutenticationHeader object in spring.net, but there's not much information about this subject... I also posted on the spring.net forum but it seems like it has been inactive for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that might help you

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/SOAPHeaderAuthentication.aspx